# How to select at the same time from two Listbox?

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *


master = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(master)
listbox.pack()
listbox.insert(END, "a list entry")

for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
    listbox.insert(END, item)

listbox2 = Listbox(master)
listbox2.pack()
listbox2.insert(END, "a list entry")

for item in ["one", "two", "three", "four"]:
    listbox2.insert(END, item)

master.mainloop()
```

The code above creates a `tkinter` window with two listboxes. But there's a problem if you want to retrieve the values from both because, as soon as you select a value in one, it deselects whatever you selected in the other.

Is this just a limitation developers have to live with?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Short answer: set the value of the `exportselection` attribute of all listbox widgets to False or zero.

From [a pythonware overview](http://www-acc.kek.jp/WWW-ACC-exp/KEKB/control/Activity/Python/TkIntro/introduction/listbox.htm) of the listbox widget:

> By default, the selection is exported
>   to the X selection mechanism. If you
>   have more than one listbox on the
>   screen, this really messes things up
>   for the poor user. If he selects
>   something in one listbox, and then
>   selects something in another, the
>   original selection is cleared. It is
>   usually a good idea to disable this
>   mechanism in such cases. In the
>   following example, three listboxes are
>   used in the same dialog:
>
> ```
> b1 = Listbox(exportselection=0)
> for item in families:
>     b1.insert(END, item)
>
> b2 = Listbox(exportselection=0)
> for item in fonts:
>     b2.insert(END, item)
>
> b3 = Listbox(exportselection=0)
> for item in styles:
>     b3.insert(END, item)
> ```

The definitive documentation for tk widgets is based on the Tcl language rather than python, but it is easy to translate to python. The `exportselection` attribute can be found on the [standard options manual page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/options.htm#M-exportselection).

Answer (score 8):

`exportselection=0` when defining a listbox seems to take care of this issue.