# Make Tkinter.Listbox selection persist

Tags: python, python-2.7, listbox, tkinter

I have a program where I need to take a selection from Tkinter.Listbox and an entry field and do something with that data. However, if I highlight any text within the entry field (i.e., to delete previous entry), the Listbox selection is cleared. How can I overcome it so that the Listbox selection persists?

```
import Tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
listbox = tk.Listbox(master)
listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
items = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for item in items:
    listbox.insert(tk.END, item)

efield = tk.Entry(master)
efield.grid(row=1, column=0)

tk.mainloop()
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Type something in the entry field.
2. Select something in the listbox.
3. Highlight whatever you entered in the entry field => selection in the listbox gets cleared.

---

This related question with similar issue [How to select at the same time from two Listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756662/using-multiple-listboxes-in-python-tkinter) suggests to use `exportselection=0`, which doesn't seem to work for me. In such case `selection = listbox.selection_get()` throws an error while the right line is still highlighted.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but it was the first google search result when I came across the same problem. I was seeing odd behavior using 2 list boxes when using `selection_get()` and also the selection persistence issue.

`selection_get()` is a universal widget method in Tkinter, and was returning selections that were last made in other widgets, making for some really strange behavior. Instead, use the ListBox method `curselection()` which returns the selected indices as a tuple, then you can use the ListBox's `get(index)` method to get the value if you need.

To solve the persistence issue, set `exportselection=0` when instantiating the ListBox instance.

```
list_box = tk.Listbox(master, exportselection=False)

...

selected_indices = list_box.curselection()
first_selected_value = list_box.get(selected_indices[0])
```

Comment: Using `exportselection=0` on `Listbox` did the trick for me. I don't understand the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

As for now, I wasn't able to cleanly overcome the problem. One way around is to create a variable which will store the selected list value on click:

```
selected = None
def onselect(e):
    global selected
    selected = listbox.selection_get()

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)
```

This doesn't keep the highlight, but the selection is now stored in a variable and can be used further.